# Putty Google Cloud compute

Tags: putty, google-cloud-platform

I am very new to google cloud and putty. 
My question is when I open putty on my computer and type in the EXTERNAL IP into putty. I screen opens up and asks me for a Login.. my question is what do i put in for my login. Is it the google username account ? a better question would be where can I find the login and password that I need to login to VM

Answer (score 7):

Here's some info on how to **get you started**. You shouldn't have to enter a login password. If you really want to, first connect via SSH keys and then use root privileges to change the password for the account to what ever you want.

You have a few different options, I'm just going to mention a few. To get into your GCE instance, you're going to need SSH keys setup and your client (Putty) configured to use them.

First option: [SSH straight from the browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser). This way you can skip the setup, but it's probably best to get your Putty properly configured.

Second option: Configure your SSH keys and Putty to SSH to GCE instances:

1. Follow [this article(Linux/OSX)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#connecting_from_linux_or_osx_workstations) or [this article(Windows)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#connecting_from_windows_workstations) to create and add your SSH keys to the
   metadata for your Project.
2. Once you have your keys added to the Dev Console, setup Putty like this:

   - Open Putty
   - In the 'Host Name' field enter `[username]@[external_IP]`, where username will be the same as the one used to create your SSH keys. In summary, the comment at the end of your SSH key.
   - In Putty, on the left, expand the 'SSH' section and click 'Auth'.
   - Click on 'Browse' and select the private SSH key you created earlier.
   - Click back on 'Session' on the left, and 'Open' the connection.

You should now be good to go.